# Javascript Window PopUp

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to Javascript and not sure how to approach this. How can I create a chromeless window using Javascript?

Further more, let say I have multiple images, instead of opening a new pop up every time, just to reload the image that was selected on the same pop up window.

Can this be done?

**Update:**
Is there a way to use only one window.open to open multiple files or do I need to create multiple window.open for each file?

Comment: What is your definition of "chromeless"?

Comment: That removes traditional windows browser user interface.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look into [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and read up on the "Modal" section.
2. You can use Jquery for this via a swap:

--

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
    var thmb = this;
    var src = this.src;
    $('.bottlesWrapper img').fadeOut(400,function(){
        thmb.src = this.src;
        $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/asixuj/4/edit

Comment: I know about bootstrap and the Modal but I want to try to do it only using javascript. Trying to get better using just javascript.

Comment: I have a question for you: This is what I am using to create a new window when the user clicks on a pdf file: <a href="#" onclick="window.open('Downloads/ 275.pdf', 'mywindow','resizable=yes'> which works fine. But let say I want to click on a different pdf file, it wont open until the previous window is close. Is there a way to open a new window or override the previous pdf to show the new one the user has selected?